# How to bind an event to a dynamically created element within another dynamically created element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Binding events to a dynamically created element that has a static ancestor is fairly easy using jQuery, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements):

```
$(staticAncestors).on(eventName, dynamicChild, function() {});
```

But what if the `dynamicChild` is of a `dynamicAncestor`? Is there any way to make the following work:

```
$(dynamicAncestors).on(eventName, dynamicChild, function() {});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `on`, you should bind to the nearest static parent element. In some cases, that may be `body`:

```
$('body').on(eventName, 'dynamic-element', function() {  });
```

Binding all events to `body` is generally bad practice though, so it's difficult to answer your question more thoroughly without seeing your DOM. But binding to the nearest static parent will work for what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If `dynamicAncestors` is a selector, **no**. The element **must** exist when you bind the event handler. This is the key point of event delegation: using a static parent as a middleware for listening to events of (dynamically generated) descendants. You are probably looking for the following syntax:

```
$('staticParentOfdynamicAncestors').on(
   eventName, 
  'dynamicAncestors dynmaicChild', 
  function() {}
);
```

Check [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).